# How to avoid adding a new row if the user is not finished fill-up the rows and clicking the save button?

Tags: javascript, dom

The problem is when I didn't click the save button and didn't fill-up the row consist of firstName. It still adding a new row after I click the 'Add New Row' button. The worse part is I still get the same id's. Could somebody help me with my problem on my validation?

```
function Add() {
        isAdd = true;
        if (PersonList.length == 0) {
            for (var index = 0; index < tblInfo.childNodes.length; index++) {
                if (tblInfo.childNodes[index].nodeName == "TR") {
                    tblInfo.removeChild(tblInfo.childNodes[index]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        newTr = document.createElement("TR");
        newTd = document.createElement("TD");
        textNode = document.createTextNode(id);
        details.push(textNode.nodeValue);
        newTd.appendChild(textNode);
        newTd.style.textAlign = "center";
        newTr.appendChild(newTd);

        newTd = document.createElement("TD");
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        details.push(input);
        newTd.appendChild(input);
        newTd.style.textAlign = "center";
        newTr.appendChild(newTd);

        newTd = document.createElement("TD");
        btn = document.createElement("button");
        textNode = document.createTextNode("UPDATE");
        btn.appendChild(textNode);
        btn.setAttribute("class", "btnUpdate");
        btn.disabled = true;
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {Update(this);});
        newTd.appendChild(btn);
        newTr.appendChild(newTd);

        btn = document.createElement("button");
        textNode = document.createTextNode("SAVE");
        btn.appendChild(textNode);
        btn.setAttribute("class", "btnSave");
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {Save(details);});
        newTd.appendChild(btn);
        newTr.appendChild(newTd);

        btn = document.createElement("button");
        textNode = document.createTextNode("CANCEL");
        btn.appendChild(textNode);
        btn.setAttribute("class", "btnCancel");
        btn.addEventListener("click", Cancel);
        newTd.appendChild(btn);
        btn.setAttribute("id", id);
        newTr.appendChild(newTd);

        tblInfo.appendChild(newTr);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to avoid being able to click the Add New Row button without filling the first name field right? If so, what you can try is first retrieve the value of the field, and use a simple if statement. If it has some value, then you add the new row, if not, nothing happens or you can show some kind of info to the user. Hope this helps! Bye